# How do you search an album in a listBox and connect it to an AVL tree or a Binary Search Tree? C#

Tags: c#

I need the albums that appear in the listbox, to have a search function that passes through the AVL Tree or Binary Search Tree.

This is my code for the AVLTree class

```
    class AVLTree<T> : BSTree<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        public new void InsertItem(T item)
        {
            insertItem(item, ref root);
        }

        private void insertItem(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
        {
                 if (tree == null)
            tree = new Node<T>(item);
        else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
            insertItem(item, ref tree.Left);
        else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
        insertItem (item, ref tree.Right);
                 tree.balanceFactor = Height(tree.Left)-Height(tree.Right);
                 if (tree.balanceFactor <= -2)
                     rotateLeft(ref tree);
                 if (tree.balanceFactor >= 2)
                     rotateRight(ref tree);



       }


        private void rotateLeft(ref Node<T> tree)
        {             

            if (tree.Right.balanceFactor > 0)  
                rotateRight(ref tree.Right);
            Node<T> pivot = tree.Right;
            tree.Right = pivot.Left;
            pivot.Left = tree;
            tree = pivot;



        }

        private void rotateRight(ref Node<T> tree)
        {

            if (tree.Left.balanceFactor > 0) 
                rotateLeft(ref tree.Left);
            Node<T> pivot = tree.Left;              
            tree.Left = pivot.Right;
            pivot.Right = tree;
            tree = pivot;
        }
    }

}
```

FormClass:

//search button

```
    private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //BASIC SEARCH NOT SUITABLE YET
    {
        listBox1.ClearSelected();
        int index = listBox1.FindString(SearchText.Text);
        if (index <0)

        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item not found.");
            SearchText.Text = String.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
        }
```

.

//ARTIST CLASS
{
    class Artist : IComparable
    {

```
    public String name; //changed to public
    public String member;
    public LinkedList<String> Album;

    public Artist(String artistname, String members, String[] albName) 
        {
            name = artistname;
            member = members;
            Album = new LinkedList<String>(albName);
        }

    public LinkedList<String> getAlbum()
    {
        return Album;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Artist) //Artist name comparison
        {
            Artist other = (Artist)obj;
            return name.CompareTo(other.name);
        }
        if (obj is string) //Album comparison
        {
            Artist other = (Artist)obj;
            return name.CompareTo(other.Album);
        }
        else
            return -999;  //Comparison can not be made
    }
}
```

}

//ALBUM  CLASS

class Album
    {

```
    private String title;
    private String daterel;

    public Album(String aTitle, String saleDate) 
    {
        daterel = saleDate;
        title = aTitle;           
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to only display the data that matches a "search" string in the listbox, or are you trying to select that data? Also, is this ASP.NET or WinForms or WPF? (They might have subtly different APIs for listboxes but it's easier to not expect people to know those details by heart.)

Comment: I don't see anything about an AVL tree or Binary Search Tree in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Provided this is Winforms, you could add the items in listbox1 to an array, then iterate through them calling your search function on each.